# Code level obfuscator vs assembly obfuscator

Tags: c#, obfuscation

I've tried some assembly obfuscators but except a few commercial ones, others are not compatible with my project.

A code level obfuscation is enough for my scenario but I want to know the key diffrences and also is there any free code level obfuscator?

Comment: Ok. please just answer the second part -> Free code level obfuscator for C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a single person project (personal hobby), then the free [Dotfuscator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotfuscator#Editions) tool built into Visual Studio might be good enough. The provided link lists the breakdown of limitations provided by the free version.

If you're not just a lone developer, then they require you to get a license.

Comment: Does it (Dotfuscator) a code level obfuscator? (I thought it's an assembly obfuscator)

Comment: The community version provides some [code renaming tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227240(VS.90).aspx) (old comparison) to obfuscate your code that is reflected in the generated assembly ([newer comparison](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/compare-editions)). I don't personally use it, so I can't really commit to saying how well it works, but I have _always_ heard good things, which is why I suggested it.

Comment: (Ran out of characters): I think you might find [this post on the Dotfuscator Community edition useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030136/how-good-is-dotfuscator-community-edition-what-is-good-enough-obfuscator).